# Import Error: Cannot import name 'statfunc' (pymc3 module already installed)

Tags: python, conda, bayesian, pymc3

When i try to import pymc3 module on my Jupyter notebook
using  `import pymc3 as pm` i get the following error

````
```ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2e5c536b7c65> in <module>
----> 1 import pymc3 as pm

~\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\__init__.py in <module>
     19 from . import sampling
     20 
---> 21 from .diagnostics import *
     22 from .backends.tracetab import *
     23 from .backends import save_trace, load_trace

~\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\diagnostics.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from .stats import statfunc, autocov
      5 from .util import get_default_varnames
      6 from .backends.base import MultiTrace
ImportError: cannot import name 'statfunc'```
````

I have pymc3 installed. See below. I am not sure what is needed to import statfunc. Can someone advise?

````
```base) C:\Users\gosal\Anaconda3_2\envs\py3>pip install pymc3
Requirement already satisfied: pymc3 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (3.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contextvars; python_version < "3.7" in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in c:\users\gosal\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pymc3) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.7.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastprogress>=0.2.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: arviz>=0.9.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (3.7.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: theano>=1.0.4 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.18.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.5.1 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pymc3) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: immutables>=0.9 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from contextvars; python_version < "3.7"->pymc3) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from h5py>=2.7.0->pymc3) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: netcdf4 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: xarray>=0.11 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.0 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.18.0->pymc3) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.18.0->pymc3) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from packaging->arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cftime in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from netcdf4->arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.2 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from xarray>=0.11->arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (49.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\gosal\anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0->arviz>=0.9.0->pymc3) (0.10.0)```
````

Comment: Are you trying to use an env called `py3`? It isn't activated when installing/checking with pip. I'd guess that mixing Conda and Pip you ended up with multiple versions installed in **base** and what Pip is showing you is not representative of what is being loaded in Jupyter. E.g., `pymc3/diagnostics.py` was removed after v3.7, so in the Jupyter notebook it is definitely trying to load something else.